# PostgreSQL not returning records just inserted

Tags: postgresql

I am trying to insert (clone) some records in a table and need to get source ids and ids that got generated. This simplified example demonstrates my issue. After new records are created, referencing their ids in a SELECT produces no results even though records do get created and subsequent SELECT on the table shows them. It feels like insert and select are happening in different transaction scopes.

```
CREATE TABLE tbl_value(
    id int4 NOT NULL GENERATED ALWAYS AS identity PRIMARY KEY,
    some_id INTEGER NOT NULL,
    value VARCHAR NOT NULL
);

INSERT INTO tbl_value(some_id, value) VALUES(1000, 'value 1'), (1000, 'value 2'), (1000, 'value 3');

with 
outer_input as
(
    select id, some_id, value from tbl_value where id in (1,2)
),

inner_insert as 
(
    INSERT INTO tbl_value(some_id, value) 
    select 2000, value from outer_input 
    returning id
)

select * from tbl_value v inner join inner_insert i on v.id = i.id;
```

Comment: From here [WITH](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/sql-select.html#SQL-WITH) "The primary query and the WITH queries are all (notionally) executed at the same time. This implies that the effects of a data-modifying statement in WITH cannot be seen from other parts of the query, other than by reading its RETURNING output. " So you can get the returned ids you just won't see the new data.

Comment: …and the fix is to just use `RETURNING *` instead of the join

Comment: Hmm, ok, I might be able to do something with that, I'll give it a try

Comment: Cool, thank you, using RETURNING * gives me everything in the inner_insert so I can inner join other tables that I need in my function.